# How do I remove Ubuntu packages from Linux Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, package-management, upgrade, distributions

I'm pretty new to using Linux distributions and for some reason I decided to install some Ubuntu packages on my Mint distribution a few months ago.

I recently attempted to update the distribution of Mint by running `sudo apt-get update`, however, the installer seems to also be updating all of the Ubuntu Saucy packages which are on my computer. Is there any way I can remove those packages? If that's not possible, then can I block Ubuntu from being updated?

Comment: Updating your mint will and should also update the base Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Seems that my question is kinda pointless now.

Comment: No actually, people might get curious about why Mint installs ubuntu stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually Mint Petra uses Ubuntu repositories for stuff and only installs some extras. Removing these packages will most surely bork your system. The [official default Mint](http://hajimu.org/?p=3590) `sources.list` includes those repositories. You can disable them but again, you should strive to have your system upgraded with all the latest packages. See instructions below:

---

### To deactivate/remove the saucy repositories:

Remove all the saucy entries of all your sources.list:

```
sudo sed -i '/saucy/d' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Update.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

### NO A GOOD IDEA, to remove the saucy packages

Install aptitude. Why? Because it makes your life easier:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

now what? Well, we will use aptitude to upgrade, downgrade and remove any non Mint packages:

```
aptitude search '?and(~i, !?origin(mint))'
```

This will give you a list of all the package that are installed that are not from mint repositories. Now with that list, you can start downgrading packages.

```
sudo aptitude install '?narrow(?and(~i, !?origin(mint)), ?any-version(*))'
```

This will install any package that is installed, not from mint and any version available. I think that it needs some fine tunning, but is a good start.

Comment: Braiam, that's probably a Very Bad Idea. Since Mint is based on Ubuntu, a _lot_ of Ubuntu packages are included and come from the Ubuntu repos and not Mint's. Removing all packages downloaded from the Ubuntu repos would probably bork the system completely.

Comment: @terdon if I'm not mistaken, Linux Mint has their very own repositories http://packages.linuxmint.com/ and changed enough to be called a fork. Mixing forks repos isn't going to do any good since ol' days ;).

Comment: Yes, but most of their base packages come from the Ubuntu repos, they just add the extras to their own repositories. See [here](http://hajimu.org/?p=3590) for the default `sources.list` which also contains UBuntu's repos.

Comment: After doing the search `aptitude search '?and(~i, !?origin(mint))'` I see [a ton of packages](http://pastie.org/pastes) which seem to be relevant. For example, I'm pretty sure that `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` should not be removed.

Comment: @Lirik in fact, none of them should be removed. You have not said which version of Mint you are using but if it is the latest, you _should_ have packages from Saucy. What makes you think these should not be updated? See my comments to Braiam above.

Comment: @tredon I have Olivia and I'm trying to update to Petra.

Comment: @Lirik see this, about how to upgrade http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2